# Estimating current pulse amplitude from some known parameters

Tags: current-source, pulse

How to estimate the current pulse amplitude, if we know the pulse period Tp(1us), pulse duration tp(0.5ns) the resistor value R1(330 Ohm) and the settled value of voltage value which is 132mV?

In my experiment, I will be able to measure R1(but not C2), settled voltage value, and will know pulse current's period Tp and duration tp. And want to derive current amplitude of the current source.

Is there an analytic way to obtain a formula for the current pulse amplitude knowing the above parameters?

[image]

Voltage across R1= Rload // Rscope:

[image]

Pulse current(in this example it is 1A, which I want to derive):

[image]

If it is not possible without knowing C2. Please consider also value of C2 is also known.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the average voltage across a 330 \$\Omega\$ resistor is 132 mV, then the average current is

$$<I> = \frac{0.132}{330} = 400 \mu A$$

The frequency of the pulses is 1 MHz, so the charge delivered in each pulse must be 400 pC.

If current in the pulses was constant for the duration of the pulse (i.e. your pulse were perfectly square, and had no rise or fall time), then that current would be the charge delivered divided by the pulse duration, or

$$I = \frac{400 pC}{0.5 ns} = 800 mA$$

However, your pulse is not perfectly square, but trapezoidal. So you will need to know the actual shape of the pulse, and not just it's duration to find its peak current. (Of course you can read it from the simulation, but I don't think that is what you are looking for ;-) ). Without knowing the shape information for the pulse, the best you can do is know the charge delivered per pulse.

As a side note, you do not need to know the value of C2, because it doesn't affect the average voltage drop across R1.

Answer (score 0):

Well, notice that the voltage across the capacitor and resistor is given by:

$$\text{V}\left(t\right)=\mathscr{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\text{i}_\text{source}\left(\text{s}\right)\cdot\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}\cdot\frac{1}{\text{sC}}}{\displaystyle\text{R}+\frac{1}{\text{sC}}}\right]_{\left(t\right)}=\int\limits_0^t\text{I}_\text{source}\left(\tau\right)\cdot\frac{\displaystyle\exp\left(\frac{\displaystyle\tau-t}{\displaystyle\text{CR}}\right)}{\displaystyle\text{C}}\space\text{d}\tau\tag1$$

Now, you can plug in the mathematical description of the pulse train and solve for the voltage by evaluating the integral.

**Edit**, notice that the mathematical description of the pulse train is given by:

$$\displaystyle\text{I}_\text{source}\left(t\right)=\begin{cases}
\frac{\displaystyle\hat{\text{i}}\text{mod}\left(t,\tau_1+\tau_2+\tau_3+\tau_4\right)}{\displaystyle\tau_1}&\space\text{if}&0\le\text{mod}\left(t,\tau_1+\tau_2+\tau_3+\tau_4\right)<\tau_1\\
\\
\hat{\text{i}}&\space\text{if}&\tau_1\le\text{mod}\left(t,\tau_1+\tau_2+\tau_3+\tau_4\right)<\tau_1+\tau_2\\
\\
\hat{\text{i}}\left(\frac{\displaystyle\tau_1+\tau_2+\tau_3}{\displaystyle\tau_3}-\frac{\displaystyle\text{mod}\left(t,\tau_1+\tau_2+\tau_3+\tau_4\right)}{\displaystyle\tau_3}\right)&\space\text{if}&\tau_1+\tau_2\le\text{mod}\left(t,\tau_1+\tau_2+\tau_3+\tau_4\right)<\tau_1+\tau_2+\tau_3\\
\\
0&\space\text{if}&\tau_1+\tau_2+\tau_3\le\text{mod}\left(t,\tau_1+\tau_2+\tau_3+\tau_4\right)<\tau_1+\tau_2+\tau_3+\tau_4
\end{cases}\tag2$$

Where for your case we have:

$$\tau_1=100\cdot10^{-12}\tag3$$
$$\tau_2=300\cdot10^{-12}\tag4$$
$$\tau_3=100\cdot10^{-12}\tag5$$
$$\tau_4=\frac{1999}{2000000000}\tag6$$

Answer (score 0):

As others have already said you can decide from the shown voltage that the average current from the current source is 0.13 V/330 ohms i.e. 0.39 mA and the pulses are so short and occur so often that the RC circuit filters any fast transients in the voltage curve to invisible when the visual resolution in the curve image is this low. There's only the slow rise from 0 to the steady state voltage 0.13 volts.

In theory you could well calculate the capacitance of C2 from the value of R1 and the RC time constant that can be seen in your voltage curve. The time constant is the time when 63% of the transient has been happened.

But you cannot decide the actual height of the current pulse without knowing how long the pulse is and which is it's form as seen in an oscilloscope. You know only it's average current is 0.39 milliamperes. Make the pulse shorter then it should be higher for the same shown voltage curve.

Answer (score 0):

I will not explain the whole thing but I'll give you a tip: You can do a Norton - Thevenin conversion:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWVtej.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

As you might remember, V1's voltage will be the multiplication of I1's current and the resistance, R, as shown above.

For your circuit, voltage source's amplitude becomes 1 Amp x 330 Ohms = 330 Volts and the timing parameters remain unchanged i.e. `PULSE(0 330 0 100p 100p 300p 1u)` for LTspice *(If you simulate the converted circuit you'll see the output waveform does not change)*.

From here, the circuit turns into a series RC circuit, and you can, hopefully, workout the rest relatively easier.